# Active Model Serializer causes endless loop and SystemStackError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have a serializer for my `Client` model that causes an endless loop when I include `has_many :referrers` in the `ClientSerializer`.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :referrals, class_name: 'Referral', foreign_key: 'referrer_id'
    has_many :referrals_as_referred, class_name: 'Referral', foreign_key: 'referred_id'
    has_many :referred_clients, through: :referrals, source: :referred
    has_many :referrers, through: :referrals_as_referred, source: :referrer
end

class Referral < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :referrer, class_name: 'Client'
    belongs_to :referred, class_name: 'Client'
end
```

In my serializer, the following works successfully:

```
class API::ClientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :referrers

    # has_many :referrers
    has_many :referrals

    def referrers
        object.referrers
    end
end
```

But this causes the infinite loop and stack error:

```
class API::ClientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    has_many :referrers
    has_many :referrals
end
```

Why is this occurring?

Comment: You might try using the `foreign_key:` or `primary_key:` attributes in your `belongs_to` statement.